# Logetich M705 Wheel Tilt not functioning

Tags: mouse

I recently switched from my antiquated Keyboard and Mouse set (EasyCall Desktop) to the MK710, which uses the M705 mouse.
Previously, the side tile on the wheel would function as normal on the old mouse. However, the new mouse gives no response to the side tilts.  I don't need anything fancy. Just want the left and right tilts to return their normal functions. Any ideas on whats wrong and how to get this working again?

Thanks!

Comment: Look if the keys are recognized, do 'xev |grep button ' in terminal and use the buttons in the white window.
They should act as button+number

Comment: The buttons work as they should. The command returns button 6 and button 7, as they should. Its just they no longer function in any application as they should normally function.

Comment: I just plugged in my old mouse and did the test above. Left and right tilt does not return any results. But the xinput test confirms that the left and right tilt on the old mouse is bound to left arrrow and right arrow. The screen returns ^[[D and ^[[C when I tilt left and right, respectively.

So now the question becomes, how do I bind button 6 and button 7 to left and right arrow keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:
1. install xbindkeys and xte:

```
sudo apt install xbindkeys xautomation
```

2. Now write a default xbindkey-file with:

   xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc

Edit the file with scratch or: `nano .xbindkeysrc`

Look if there's allready an entry for your buttons, edit it or make new entrys as following:

```
#Tilt Left
"xte 'key Left'"
   b:6

#Tilt Right
"xte 'key Right'"
   b:7
```

Or vice-versa (depending which number is right and left). The commands are case-sensitive! 
Save the file. (with nano it's Ctrl+O).

Run xbindkey in terminal. If it's working add xbindkey to your startup-applications. (System-settings-> Application)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.      Out of curiosity, what is the default function of a tilt right or tilt left in ElementaryOS?

Comment: It's exactly what you wanted for my MX Anywhere 2, so I guess this is default.